# Proof of Hadamard's formula for Radius of Convergence of Power Series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, proof-explanation

Hadamard formula says: For power series $\Sigma _{n=1}^\infty a_nz^n$,   let $$\limsup_{n}|a_n|^\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{R}.$$
Then the series is divergent for $|z|>R$.

But i'm not satisfied with the proof ,because i think it only implies that $\Sigma _{n=1}^\infty |a_nz^n|$ is divergent.

Comment: There are a couple of proofs.  I'm satisfied with the one I know.  Could you describe the one you know?  That might make it easier to explain.

Comment: @Callus we choose $\epsilon$ that $(\frac{1}{r}-\epsilon)|z|>1$,then for large $n$,$|a_n|^\frac{1}{n}>\frac{1}{r}-\epsilon$.and the series of absolute values is divergent in comparison with geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

If $0<R<\infty$ and $|z|>R,$ let $|z|=\frac {R}{1-d}$ with $0<d<1.$ There are infinitely many $n$ for which $|a_n|^{1/n}>\frac {1-d/2}{R}.$ So there are infinitely many $n$ for which $$|a_nz^n|>\frac {(1-d/2)^n}{R^n}\cdot \frac {R^n}{(1-d)^n}=\frac {(1-d/2)^n}{(1-d)^n}\ge 1.$$ So the sequence  $(a_nz^n)_{n\ge 0}$ of the terms of the series does not converge to $0.$ Therefore the sequence $(\sum_{j=0}^n a_jz^j)_{n\ge 0}$ of finite partial sums of the series does not satisfy the Cauchy Condition, i.e. the series does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\;|z|<r\;$ , then

$$|a_nz^n|\le |a_n|r^n\;\;\;(**)$$

but

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\frac1r\implies \;\text{for almost all index}\;\;n\;,$$

$$\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\le\frac1r=r^{-1}\implies |a_n|\le r^{-n}$$

and thus in (**) we get

$$|a_nz^n|\le1\;,\;\;\;\text{for almost all}\;\;n$$

and we get absolute convergence. There are proofs in the language of $\;\epsilon\;$ , too.

Comment: i agree u in case $|z|<r$,my question involves the other case.